# Android studio EditText doesnt load TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im working in a fragment where I want the user to input an answer and then when clicking a button, a textview should show Correct.
This is my code

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private EditText userAnswer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, null);
        userAnswer = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final String theAnswer = (userAnswer.getText().toString());
        Button submit = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submitBtn1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (theAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Germany")) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.showCorrect);
                    tv.setText("Correct!");
                }
            }
        });
        return v;


    }
}
```

However, when Germany is typed, the textView is still just showing 'x' (which I set it to show originally)

Relevant XML's are

```
<Button
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/submitBtn1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Write answer and press enter"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/showCorrect"
    android:layout_below="@+id/skipBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />
```

What has gone wrong?

Comment: you trying to find textView on Button `TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.showCorrect);` 
means when you clicked on object `onClick(View v)` gets object you clicked in view. so you need initialize with  your userAnswer object

Comment: @user5599807 what do you mean initialise with userAnswer object? can you be more explicit about the code i should change please

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this line :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, null);
    userAnswer = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.showCorrect);
    Button submit = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submitBtn1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String theAnswer = (userAnswer.getText().toString());
            if (theAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Germany")) {
                tv.setText("Correct!");
            }
        }
    });
    return v;


}
```

i.e : in your code userAnswer value is always the same (not checked on Button click)

Comment: I changed the code to this, but that crashes the app when I press submit

Comment: no error, can't get stacktrace to show anything. it didnt crash before changing the code

Comment: This code shouldn't crash, but `userAnswer` either needs to be `final` or needs to be a class variable in order to compile.

Comment: @Ahmed Abidi in your sample TextView tv should be final. in other case it won't be acessible in onClick

Answer (score 1):

Code needed to be changed to:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private EditText userAnswer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, null);
        userAnswer = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.showCorrect); //changed
        Button submit = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submitBtn1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String theAnswer = (userAnswer.getText().toString());
                if (theAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Germany")) {
                    //TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.showCorrect);
                    tv.setText("Correct!");
                }

                // updateScore();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```